# AVPlayerViewControllerで動画再生すると画面が真っ暗で再生されます

Tags: ios, objective-c

AVPlayerViewControllerで動画再生を行っています。

AVPlayerViewControllerを継承したコントローラクラスを作成し、以下のコードで再生しています。

```
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
[self.player play];
```

再生を開始すると、時々画面が真っ暗になり映像が表示されません。音声は再生されています。
連続で再現したり、なかなか再現しなかったりします。

iOSバージョン：10.0.2

回避策のアドバイスをよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

公式ドキュメントにAVPlayerViewControllerのサブクラスを作るなと書いてあります。
https://developer.apple.com/reference/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller

> Do not subclass AVPlayerViewController. Overriding this class’s methods is unsupported and results in undefined behavior.

こちらを参考に実装してみてはいかがでしょうか？
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31277658/4834226

Comment: サブクラスは不可とのこと知りませんでした。試してみます。ありがとうございました。

Comment: もし解決済みであればベストアンサーを選んでみてください。